# EF Core with AutoMapper

Tags: automapper, asp.net-core-webapi, dto, ef-core-2.1

I have a DTO containing properties and a Model, eg student can have more than one module and a module can be associated with more than one student. the properties are mapping fine but the Model doesn't map.

```
 public class GetStudentByIdMapping : Profile
{
    public GetStudentByIdMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<Student,StudentDetails>();
        CreateMap<Module, StudentDetails>()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.StudentModules.ModuleName, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.ModuleName))
            .ForPath(dest => dest.StudentModules.ModuleCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.ModuleCode))
            .ForPath(dest => dest.StudentModules.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Description))
            .ReverseMap();


    }
}


    public async Task<StudentDetails> GetStudent(int studentId)
    {
        var student = context.Student
                             .Where(s => s.StudentId == studentId)
                             .FirstOrDefault();

        var module = await context.Order
                           .Include(m => m.Module)
                           .Where(o => o.StudentId == studentId)
                           .Select(m => m.Module).ToListAsync();


        var studMap =  Mapper.Map<StudentDetails>(student);
        Mapper.Map<StudentDetails>(module);


        return studMap;
    }
```

These are the ViewModels I want to map to the Models Model in the StudentDetails ViewModel

```
public class StudentDetails
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public StudentModule StudentModules { get; set; }

}
public class StudentModule
{
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

These are my Entities generated by EF Core

```
public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Order = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
}

public partial class Module
{
    public Module()
    {
        Order = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public int? LectureId { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ModulePath { get; set; }

    public virtual Lecture Lecture { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We are not clear about their structure and fields.I suggest you provide us with all the models involved in.

Comment: I have added the ViewModels and my Entites

Comment: Did my answer help you solved your issue? If it solved, please accpet it as the answer, which will help others with the same problem.If not, please tell us your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to **pass the created destination to the second map call**:

Just try the following code when mapping:

```
 var studMap = Mapper.Map<Student,StudentDetails>(student);
 Mapper.Map<Module,StudentDetails>(module,studMap);
```

Then the `studMap` will receive all mapped fields value.